Issue with Psych::DisallowedClass Exception when using reify in PaperTrail with Sinatra
I am working on a Ruby project using Sinatra version 3.0.6 and Ruby version 3.0.0. I am using the PaperTrail gem (version 15.1.0) to track changes in my models for auditing and version control purposes.
The PaperTrail gem allows me to revert a model to a previous version using the reify method. However, I am encountering an error when attempting to revert a model to a previous state. Here is a brief explanation and the relevant code snippet:
Purpose of PaperTrail:
PaperTrail tracks changes to your models, allowing you to see how a model looked at any stage of its lifecycle, revert to any version, or restore it after it has been destroyed.
Code Example:
item.versions[index].reify

Error Message:
Psych::DisallowedClass Exception: Tried to load unspecified class: Time

I have tried searching for solutions, but I have not been able to resolve this issue. It seems to be related to YAML serialization/deserialization. Does anyone know how to fix or work around this error?
Additional Information:

Ruby version: 3.0.0
Sinatra version: 3.0.6
PaperTrail version: 15.1.0

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Since it's tracking changes to a model, the model itself would be helpful to see. Without seeing it, my guess is that a field looks like a time object and it either needs to require "time" so that it can use that class, or to not try munging that data as a Time object.
